# How to remove the empty node in the treeview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Desired Output**
---1
--------11
---2
--------22
---3
--------33

**Actual Output:**
---(Empty Node)
--------1
-----------11
--------2
-----------22
--------3
-----------33

**If I add header to treeviewitem i get the following result:**
---Header
--------1
-----------11
--------2
-----------22
--------3
-----------33
**Here is the below XAML code**

```
<TreeView>     
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Groups,Mode=OneWay}" Header="Root">     
        <TreeViewItem.ItemsPanel>     
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>    
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Background="Transparent" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>    
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>    
        </TreeViewItem.ItemsPanel>
        <TreeViewItem.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" >
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Members,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Number"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeViewItem.Resources>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go one step deeper when you assign the ItemsSource of the TreeView itself so that the children of your root become the items for the tree view. Here's how its done

```
  <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Groups,Mode=OneWay, XPath=./*}" Header="Root" />
```

Notice **XPath** in there!

Comment: I am not using XML. Xpath cannot bind to non-xml object